# Usar {% for %} e {% if %} no template Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Tenho 3 videos salvos no banco Postgres onde eu seto um `star_date` e o vídeo só aparece no *template* quando o `start_date <= date.today()`

O meu problema está no *template*. Tenho 3 botões, um para cada vídeo, minha ideia é que qualquer vídeo que não tenha sua `start_date <= date.today()` tenha o seu botão com uma `opacity: 0.3;`

Porém da forma que estou fazendo, quando qualquer vídeo estiver ativo ele recebe o botão com a `images/01.png` e com o `<a href="0">` e qualquer um que esteja inativo recebe o botão com a `images/02.png` e com o `<a href="">`

Quando ativos preciso que o `images/01.png` tenha`<a href="0">` o `images/02.png` tenha`<a href="1">` e o `images/03.png` tenha`<a href="2">`

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

***video-list.html:***

```
<div class="numbers-video">
    <!-- MOSTRA VIDEOS ATIVOS -->
    {%for video in videos%}

        {%if video.is_visible%}
            <a href="0">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/01.png' %}" alt="01">
            </a>

        {%endif%}

        <!-- MOSTRA VIDEOS INATIVOS -->
        {%if video.is_visible == False%}
            <a href="">
                <img class="opacity-button" src="{% static 'images/02.png' %}" alt="02">
            </a>
        {%endif%}

    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

***views.py:***

```
# LISTA DOS VIDEOS
def video_list(request, position):

    if 'lead_id' in request.session:
        video = Video.objects.filter(position=position).first()
        videos = Video.objects.order_by("position").all()

        return render(request, 'video-list.html', {'video': video, 'position':position, 'videos': videos})

    return redirect('registrations:create_lead')
```

***models.py:***

```
class Video(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Link Embed')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Título')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Descrição do video')
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Estará disponível quando')
    position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Qual posição')

    @property
    def is_visible(self):
        return self.start_date <= date.today()
```

Será que alguém consegue me dar essa força ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

Antes:

***video-list:***

```html
<div class="numbers-video">
    <!-- MOSTRA VIDEOS ATIVOS -->
    {%for video in videos%}

        {%if video.is_visible%}
            <a href="0">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/01.png' %}" alt="01">
            </a>

        {%endif%}

        <!-- MOSTRA VIDEOS INATIVOS -->
        {%if video.is_visible == False%}
            <a href="">
                <img class="opacity-button" src="{% static 'images/02.png' %}" alt="02">
            </a>
        {%endif%}

    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Agora:

***video-list:***

```html
        <div class="numbers-video">
            <!-- MOSTRA VIDEOS ATIVOS -->
            {%for video in videos%}

                {%if video.is_visible%}
                    <a href="{{forloop.counter0}}">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/0' %}{{forloop.counter}}.png" alt="0{{forloop.counter}}">
                    </a>

                {%else%}
                    <a>
                        <img class="opacity-button" src="{% static 'images/0' %}{{forloop.counter}}.png" alt="0{{forloop.counter}}">
                    </a>
                {%endif%}

            {%endfor%}
        </div>
```

usando o método `{{forloop.counter}}` eu vou atribuindo um valor conforme cada item da lista no caso do `{{forloop.counter0}}` uso 0 pois o counter começa com 1, dessa forma consigo tornar dinâmica minha pagina

Answer (score 1):

```
      {%if video.is_visible == False%}
```

Deveria ser

```
      {%if not video.is_visible %}
```

ou melhor, simplesmente use

```
      {% else %}
```

Comment: então @nosklo o problema é que no `{%for%}` eu gero um botão para cada video ativo e outro botão para cada video inativo, só que da forma que estou fazendo, todos ativos sempre vão receber `<a href="0">
                            <img src="{% static 'images/01.png' %}" alt="01">
                    </a>` e todos inativos `<a href="">
                        <img class="opacity-button" src="{% static 'images/02.png' %}" alt="02">
                    </a>` e como eu tenho 3 videos eu preciso que os botões seja dinamicos, exemplo se um o video 1 e 2 estivem ativos fique ativo o botao 1 e 2

Comment: atualmente se eu tiver 2 videos ativos vou gerar 2 botoes pro video 1 e não um pra cada video, sacou ?

Comment: Não entendi @RaphaelMeloDeLima ... Se você usar um `if` com `else` dentro do `for` então pra cada vídeo ele vai gerar somente um botão, ou ativo ou inativo. Não tem como ele gerar os dois! O `else`  impede que os dois códigos sejam executados, é um ou outro

Comment: o problema era a geração de botões com propriedades diferentes, consegui resolver, vou mandar a resposta aqui

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda cara, vc sempre me da uma força por aqui, valeu mesmo